# Javascript join with special characters?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this with `.join`?

```
['Jim','Joe'].join(" &bull; ")
```

desired output:

```
jim &bull; joe
```

EDIT:

Based on Quentin's answer, this is possible with the unicode escape sequence like so:

`['Jim','Joe'].join(' \u2022\ ')`

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: What you want to do with joined string?

Comment: ['jim','joe'].join(" &bull; ") outputs -> "jim &bull; joe".

Comment: it depends on where your output is. ´alert´ will not work. Inside of an element is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and that is the code to do it, *assuming* that you then do something that causes the text to be treated as HTML.

`&bull;` has no special meaning in JavaScript.

If you want a literal • in the output, then use a literal •.

```js
alert(['Jim','Joe'].join(" • "))
```

(Or you could use a JavaScript [unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings)).

Comment: "unicode escape sequence" that's what I was looking for! Thanks!